# R: Order columns in a chart by reverse alphabetical

Tags: r

I have a table like the following

```
Name, Value
A, 2
B, 1
```

I then draw it using a ggplot bar chart.

However, I would like the order to be B first and A second.

I believe changing the order of the table is in order.

When I tried

```
 sort(tableName,decreasing=TRUE)
```

then I received

```
Error: Can't combine `Name` <character> and `Value` <double>.
```

Is there any way to do this in base R, dplyr, or ggplot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier option is to convert to `factor` with `levels` specified in the `rev`erse order of the column 'Name'

```
df1$Name <- factor(df1$Name, levels = rev(unique(df1$Name)))
```

Now, we check the plot

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Name, y = Value)) + 
      geom_col()
```

-output

[image]

---

Or using `base R`

```
barplot(Value ~ Name, df1, col = 'black')
```

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B"), Value = 2:1), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: @arkrun Do you have any idea what to do if there are multiple variables? For example:
A. 2
B, 1
A, 3
B, 2
etc

Comment: @Alex Can you show the example in the post as it is not clear from the comments.  You can converrt those columns to `factor` if these are character class